# Creating a subclass (extends) via es7 decorators in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

Is there a way to dynamically subclass an es6 class via a decorator?

**WARNING:** below doesn't work, just for disucssion

```
export function dec(target) {
  var ParentClass = function(...args) {
    console.log('parent ctor')
    target.prototype.apply(this, args); // this probally is not right
  }
  return newParentClass;
}

@dec
class TestClass {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args);
    console.log('child ctor');
  }
}
```

In this example, the output would be:

```
> parent ctor
> child ctor
```

The effect would be example the same as...

```
class ParentClass extends TestClass {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(args);
    console.log('parent ctor');
  }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking for `return class extends target {constructor(...args){ console.log('parent ctor'); super(...args); }}`? I'm confused because your examples seem to have `parent` and `child` in a weird order.

Comment: You should just use `class TestClass extends decoratedWhatever(…) {`

Comment: Decorators are not part of ES7. They are still in the proposal stage.

Comment: How about via: Object.setPrototypeOf(TestClass.prototype, ParentClass)

Comment: And without performance-drawbacks: TestClass.prototype = Object.create(ParentClass.prototype);

Answer (score 0):

```
export const EnumDecorator = (enumName, initValue, options) => (Class) 
=> {
  const attrs = Enum(initValue, options);
  return class decorator extends Class {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      attrs.value = props[enumName]?.value ? props[enumName].value : 
props[enumName];
      this[enumName] = attrs;
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a way to dynamically subclass an es6 class via a decorator?

No, since there are no decorators in ES6 :-) But even if the proposal gets accepted in some future language version, you wouldn't use decorators for subclassing. Instead, just provide an expression for the superclass:

```
function dynamicExample() {
  return class ParentClass {
    constructor(...args) {
      console.log('parent ctor', args);
    }
  };
}

class TestClass extends dynamicExample() {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    console.log('child ctor');
  }
}
```